# MAX_value in 2d array for each column

Tags: c++, arrays

What is wrong with that code?
Sorry, if here bad code.
**I'm need to find max value for all column in 2d dimensional of float values, then find them sum.**
First of all I write values for Array, then display them at screen and tried to find max values for each column.

*Photo*: [didn't working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7aqS.png) and [correctly work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyDCB.png)

```
___________________   
[5.7 ; 4.2 ; 5.8;]  
[654.87; 5.86; 3.76;] - Work correctly   
[8.54; 7.54; 8.4;]  
------------------    
Max value of 1 column = A[2,1] = 654.87;      
Max value of 2 column = A[3,2] = 7.54;     
Max value of 3 column = A[3,3] = 8.4;
___________________   
[4.6 ; 2.65 ; 76.3;]  
[65.64; 7.32; 76.2;] - Work not correctly   
[654.8; 1.6; 5.7;]  
------------------    
Max value of 1 column = A[3,1] = 654.8;      
Max value of 2 column = A[3,2] = 7.32;     
Max value of 3 column = A[3,3] = 5.7; 

#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

int main(void)
{
system("cls");
int N;
int suma = 0;
A:
std::cout<<"Write array size N x N : ";
std::cin>>N;
if(N>10 || N<=1)
    {
system("cls");
std::cout<<"N must be <= 10 and > 1;"<<std::endl;
goto A;
    }
float **A = new float *[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    A[i] = new float [N];
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
    std::cout<<"A["<<i+1<<"][";
    std::cout<<j+1<<"] = ";
    std::cin>>(*(*(A+i)+j));
    }
}
system("cls");
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
if(j<N-1)
    {
std::cout<<"A["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"] = "<<*(*(A+i)+j);
std::cout<<"; ";
    }
    else
        {
std::cout<<"A["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"] = "<<*(*(A+i)+j);
std::cout<<";"<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
float *max = new float [N];
std::cout<<"------------------------------------";
std::cout<<std::endl;
for(int i = 0; i < N - (N - 1); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        *(max+j) = *(*(A+i)+j);
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if( (*(max+i)) < (*(*(A+j))+i) &&
        (*(max+i)) != ((*(*(A+j)))+i) )
        {
            *(max+i) = *(*(A+j)+i);
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if( (*(*(A+j)+i)) == (*(max+i)) )
        {
            std::cout<<"Max value of "<<i+1;
            std::cout<<" column = ";
            std::cout<<"A["<<j+1<<"]["<<i+1;
            std::cout<<"] = "<<(*(max+i));
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    suma+=(*(max+i));
}
std::cout<<"Sum of largest value = "<<suma;
_getch();
}
```

Comment: please include example input and output as text in the question. Please do not use images of text

Comment: and please format the code properly. It is almost not readable

Comment: I tried to do, what you Sayed.

Comment: If it possible, pls say me, where i do an mistake

Comment: whats that loop `for(int i = 0; i < N - (N - 1); i++)` ? `N - (N-1) == 1` that looks wrong

Comment: its like for (int i = 0; i < 1;i++); i give for max[i] first elements of i like A[0,j], I write code in Visual Studio Code, don't know how to set debugger, just dont work for me(

Comment: In correctly example its like max[0] =5.7; max[1] = 4.2; max[2] = 5.8; Sorry for bad eng

Answer (score 0):

Oh... sorry just a mistake in if() by which i losen more than 3.5 hour...

```
if( (*(max+i)) < (*(*(A+j))+i) 
                &&
    (*(max+i)) != ((*(*(A+j)))+i) )
    {...}
```

I changed it to:

```
if( (*(max + i)) < (*(*(A + j) + i))
                          &&
            (*(max + i)) != (*(*(A + j) + i))
          )
        {...}
```

After that change all work properly

Comment: (if it possible, can i have some link's for help with making readable code?). Will be such a thankfull.

Comment: Using `[]` rather than pointer arithmetics and dereference would be a bit more readable. `*( pointer_to_first_element + index)` -> `pointer_to_first_element[index]`. Using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would be much more readable.